# Controlling the Max Height of 'material-react-table'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I feel like this should be very simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm using [material-react-table](https://www.material-react-table.com/) and I can't get the tables to fit to a container.

For example : I'd expect that if a container is maxHeight of 300px, if the table rows would make it more than 300px, it'd make the table scroll and stick to the max height. However, no matter what I try, the table just overflows the container.

Any idea how to fix??

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```js
muiTableContainerProps={{ sx: { maxHeight: '500px' } }}
```